# Tensorflow error: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'cond_1/Switch'

Tags: python, if-statement, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and I am following some online exercises to get familiar with tensorflow. I want to do the following task:

> Create two tensors `x` and `y` of shape 300 from any normal
>   distribution. Use `tf.cond()` to return:
>
> - The mean squared error of `(x - y)`, if the average of all elements in    `(x - y)` is negative.
> - The sum of absolute value of all elements in the tensor `(x - y)`    otherwise.

My implementation:

```
x = tf.random_normal([300])
y = tf.random_normal([300])
mse = lambda: tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, x)
absval = lambda: tf.abs(tf.subtract(x, y))
out = tf.cond(tf.less(x, y), mse, absval)
```

Error:

```
Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'cond_1/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [300], [300]
```

Comment: `mse` ranks 0, `absval` ranks `1`, `tf.less(x, y)` ranks `1`. That's why you get the error.

Comment: @Psidom I see, thanks! Should I make pred, true_fn and false_fn same rank? The API does not explicitly say which of those should have same rank.

Comment: Pretty sure they need to have the same shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```py
x = tf.random_normal([300])
y = tf.random_normal([300])
mse = lambda: tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, x)
absval = lambda: tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(x, y)))
out = tf.cond(tf.reduce_mean(x - y) < 0, mse, absval)
```